# Xlsxwriter relative image URL

Tags: image, url, relative-path, xlsxwriter

I am wondering if it is possible to create a relative image URL e.g. ../images/image.jpg with xlsxwriter. I have not been able achieve this. I would like to insert an image with hyperlink to the full size image on my folder system. However I try I get some sort of C drive full path or the path I get does not locate the image file.

Thanks in advance,
Ian

Answer (score 1):

Thanks version 1.3.5 has fixed it

Answer (score 0):

The image urls should work in the same way as [worksheet.write_url()](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/worksheet.html#worksheet-write-url) so something like this should work:

```py
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('images_url3.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

worksheet.insert_image('B4', 'python.png', {'url': r'external:..\images\images.png'})

workbook.close()
```

However, it doesn't seem to open the link correctly. This may be a bug in XlsxWriter. [I'll look into it](https://github.com/jmcnamara/XlsxWriter/issues/751).

**Update:** There was a bug with relative links in image urls. That is fixed now in XlsxWriter version >= 1.3.5. Upgrade to the latest version and try again based on the above example.

Comment: Updated with bug fix.